# How to do this in Bigdecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm new to Java. I'm creating small tool and I'm calculating using Bidecimal.
I need to do this with bigdecimal. But I don't know how to do it?

```
balance= a%b;
```

Thanks in advance.
FxMax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for the actual operation to get a remainder of a BigDecimal, you want this:

```
    import java.math.BigDecimal;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(10.05);
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(2.10);
        BigDecimal result;

        result = a.remainder(b);
        System.out.printf("Here we are : %s", result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `remainder` method. If `a`, `b`, and `balance` are both `BigDecimals` the code would look like this:

```
balance = a.remainder(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (example):

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(a);
BigDecimal remainder = bigDecimal.remainder(new BigDecimal(b));
System.out.println("remainder: " + remainder);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder(java.math.BigDecimal)